# ansible jinja2 template output csv format

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

Trying to make a failsafe logic on output as csv as comma separated each columns by JInja2 template.
failsafe logic is supposed to tell me if any of items in modules or tech is missing.
any help appreciated to figure out the logic of jinja2 template.

**Variable**

```
swproduct_list:
  header: Sw product,sw product module,technology

  details:
    - name: BASE PACKAGE
      Modules:
        - Polygon Manager
        - Common Manager
      tech:
        - SPRING CLOUD
        - SPRING CLOUD

    - name: DMA
      Modules:
        - KUA on demand
        - KUA parameters
      tech:
        - SPRING CLOUD
        - SPRING CLOUD
```

**Desired Output**

```
Sw product,sw product module,technology
DMA,KUA on demand,SPRING CLOUD
DMA,KUA parameters,SPRING CLOUD
BASE PACKAGE,Polygon Manager,SPRING CLOUD
BASE PACKAGE,Common Manager,SPRING CLOUD
```

**Solution- Jinja2 template**

```
{% for intf in swproduct_list.details -%}
{% for ll in intf.Modules -%}
{{ intf.name }},{{ ll }},{{ intf.tech[loop.index0] }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: why to use `jinja2`? Why not use standard module `csv` or `pandas`.

Comment: This is not a "write code for me" website, so you'll want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70297713/edit) and include your attempt, along with the error that it is producing for you. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel - added.

Comment: What is the problem with your template? In other words what is your question?

Comment: From what I can see you solved your own question ? Just change the order of data in dictionary

Comment: @Zeitounator - I am trying to make failsafe ... such that if any of modules or tech is missing, it should throw error.

Comment: @user1098490 - my idea to make it failsafe ...as variable list will be huge ... now.. the idea is to jinja or ansible to throw if anything is missing before writing to csv.

Comment: This is absolutely not clear in your question. Edit it to make it more focused. Add what you have already done to try to reach that objective and tell us what is the exact problem you have.

Comment: @Zeitounator already edited in main summary of question... if that requires more clarity, let me know, i will modify it.

Comment: Create a task which checks that every element has the same number of modules and tech using the `fail` or `assert` module prior to rendering your template.

Comment: @millenion - Ok, but both problem and solution identified is already added, What not clear to u !

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator) who suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70297713/ansible-jinja2-template-output-csv-format/70323286#comment124293995_70297713):

> Create a task which checks that every element has the same number of modules and tech using the `fail` or `assert` module prior to rendering your template.

I applied the following assert method before jinja template starts and it works:

```
- set_fact:
    check_total: |
      {
      'modules_total': {{ (swproduct_list.details | selectattr('Modules', 'defined') | map(attribute='Modules') | flatten | list) | length }},
      'tech_total': {{ (swproduct_list.details | selectattr('tech', 'defined') | map(attribute='tech') | flatten | list) | length }},
      }


- debug:
    var: check_total

- assert:
    that:
    - check_total.modules_total == check_total.tech_total
    quiet: true
    fail_msg: >
      total no of modules should match with total no of tech
```